# Recomendation for SSH client for iOS

Tags: ios, ssh

What is the best SSH client app for iOS?

- Stability and security are the main issues.
- It could be paid or free.
- Easy to use is not important.

Answer (score 3):

[Prompt 2](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/prompt-2/id917437289?mt=8&uo=4&at=11l4BV) by Panic is one of the best SSH clients for iOS and has a nice UI, a bit expensive though.

With regard to security, you can add and even generate SSH keys directly in Prompt. From [the Prompt page on Panic's website](http://www.panic.com/prompt/):

> You can also PIN lock Prompt so that it remains secure even if your device is unlocked. And yes, you can also lock Prompt with Touch ID.

Answer (score 0):

[WebSSH](https://appsto.re/fr/hBOQD.i) is okay.

It has all the features you'd expect from an SSH client, the UI doesn't feel very polished though and I have a feeling the actual terminal is a JS app; it's kinda slow when the screen refreshes frequently (top/airodump-ng/etc).

Give it a try, if you're an occasional user it'll be fine, otherwise invest in Prompt 2.